# How to create own RequestException in Guzzle

Tags: guzzle

My code

```
if ($title === 'server-400') {
    throw new \GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException("
       Missing parameter
   ");
}
```

but when it run it show message like this:
Argument 2 passed to GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::__construct() must be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Mess
age\RequestInterface, none given

It required 2 parameters which are $message and $request, I do not know what is request refer to? and someone could correct this code to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we can do like this

```
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Message\Request('', '', [], null, []);
if ($title === 'server-400') {
     throw new \GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException(
         "Missing parameter",
         $request
     );
}
```